# How to group by successive periods of 7 days (weeks)

Tags: sql

From a table of `store`s that each earn a certain `revenue` on a certain `date`, I'm trying to calculate for each SKU:

- the number of stores that had stock "`nb_stores`",
- the sum of the revenue of the stores that had stock "`conditional_revenue_sum`"

Here are the table columns:

```
store, revenue, sku, qty_sold, in_stock, date
```

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT sku,
       SUM(CASE WHEN in_stock = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) nb_stores,
       SUM(CASE WHEN in_stock = TRUE THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) conditional_revenue_sum
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY sku
```

This calculates over all dates. How can I "group by week" (i.e. periods of 7 datys)? I don't want to manually a `WHERE date > '20180101' AND ...` etc clause week by week if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can use group by **week(date)** or **weekofyear(date)**

Comment: wch rdbms you are using?

Comment: It's for a generic ETL, so I was trying to have an ANSI solution. I think week() is MySQL, isn't it?